# Proxy credntials for HttpClient in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an HttpClient successfully making Http requests. I now want to accomodate users that have set up a proxy on the devices. To this end I have the code:

```
    private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        // if a proxy is enabled set it up here
        string host = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("http.proxyHost").TrimEnd('/');
        string port = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("http.proxyPort");
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(host) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(port))
        {
            httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy($"{host}:{port}", true),
                UseProxy = true
            };
        }

        if (httpClientHandler != null)
            return new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        else
            return new HttpClient();
    }
```

But in doing this I am not setting the credentials for the pre-configured proxy. Do I need to set the credentials or will this work without, equally do I need to set the proxy settings on my HttpClient at all if they are set up in OS? If I need the credentials, how do I set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user set the proxy in the device(Global proxy), and your app just need this proxy to connect internet, you do not need to set the user name and password, just get the default host and port.

If your app want to use specific proxy to connect the server, you need to set the proxy with host, port, username and password by yourself.

```
private System.Net.Http.HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        // if a proxy is enabled set it up here
        //string host = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("http.proxyHost").TrimEnd('/');
        //string port = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("http.proxyPort");
        System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = null; 
        httpClientHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
        {
             Proxy =  GetCSharpWebProxy(),
             UseProxy = true
        };
        if (httpClientHandler != null)
            return new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        else
            return new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    }

    public System.Net.WebProxy GetCSharpWebProxy()
    {
        var proxyURI = new System.Uri(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "your specific proxy host", 80));
        System.Net.ICredentials credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        System.Net.WebProxy proxy =   new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyURI, true, null, credentials);
        return proxy;
    }
```

Comment: The above solution is not using the native AndroidClientHandler. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack. The above setup does not seem tho work for it.