# Unable to record activities in JMeter for an Application (Xamarin-Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, jmeter

I am working on Xamarin-Android project and I am trying to perform load testing with JMeter but its not working. I am unable to see API requests and other details.
When i use native Android application it works fine. 
I am not enabling ProGaurd in any application.
I don't know what is causing the app to not showing API request, please suggest.

Thank You!

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it so that it's useful to others

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply, it is not working. Are you sure Jmeter supports for Xamarin applications? Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Which steps did you try from my response ? Do you get some errors  ? could you show jmeter.log

Answer (score 0):

If your Xamarin-Android application uses HTTPS and not the native one, that might be an explanation.

To enable this, ensure you add the JMeter Root Certificate generated when you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) to your Android.
It is located in jmeter/bin folder.

See "**Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording**"

If you have access to the code, you may want to disable certificate check:

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69210/https-ignore-certificate

It is also possible that your application does not correctly handle proxy (JMeter acting like that), see:

- [Proxy credntials for HttpClient in Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899353/proxy-credntials-for-httpclient-in-xamarin-android)